# Can we use a file in the reduce function in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to access a different file (other than the input file to map) in reduce function. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Distributed Cache. You can send a small file to mapper or reducer.

(if you use Java)

**In your main/driver, set file for job:**

```
job.addCacheFile(new URI("path/to/file/inHadoop/file.txt#var"));
```

Note: *var*  is a variable name used to access your file in mapper/reducer i.e. fn[1] in below code.

**In mapper or reducer, get file from context:**

```
public void setup(Context context) throws IOException{
   Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
   URI[] cacheFiles = context.getCacheFiles();
   String[] fn = cacheFiles[0].toString().split("#");
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fn[1]));
   String line = br.readLine();
   //do something with line
}
```

Note: *cacheFiles[0]* refers to the file you sent from your main/driver

[More information](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html)